# Plugin code to angular 2+

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins, angular-cli

I ran into problem trying to add jquery plugin Summernote to angular 2+(angular-cli) .

I added jquery successfully, it was executable. Than I added summernote firstly as a link to cdn (to index. html) - as [here](https://github.com/nickgaudreau/SummernoteNg2_WorkAround), then as installable webpack version with codemirror. But when I used it in code there appeared a problem - "Property 'summernote'  does not exist on type jQuery." I tried all [manuals](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc) how to add custom typings to jquery index.d.ts but it was not successful. Problem is still there.

Do you have any universal idea how to add jquery plugin to angular-cli and use it just as jquery code, not in Component or Directive way?